# Unable to change Views inside included layout

Tags: android, include, imageview

I have an xml which contains 4 included layout inside LinearLayout and I am inflating this xml in my ListAdapter.But the problem is that I am able to access the elements of first three included layout but unfortunalely i am not able to make any changes in 4th included layout For eg. changing image source of ImageView present inside my 4th included layout. Also it is not responding to any click event. I have cleaned my project and restarted it many times but nothing happens. I have debugged a lot but I am not getting any kind of Exception. FindViewById works but it is not able to change background resource of ImageView(present in included layout). I don't know what is happening right now. So plz help.

Here is my adapter code and xmls.

```
package com.embazaar.controllers;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.codebrew.embazaar.ChatActivity;
import com.codebrew.embazaar.UserProfileActivity;
import com.codebrew.lazyloading.ImageLoader;
import com.codebrew.mbazaar.R;
import com.embazaar.connection.Connection;
import com.embazaar.constants.EmBazaarApplicationGlobal;
import com.embazaar.constants.EmBazaarConstants;
import com.embazaar.objects.HeartBeatInfoBean;

public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private ArrayList<HeartBeatInfoBean> heartBeatList;
private FragmentActivity activity;
ImageLoader loader;
int screenWidth, imageWidth, imageHeight;
SharedPreferences prefs;

// private boolean isVideoPlaying = false;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public FeedListAdapter(FragmentActivity activity,
        ArrayList<HeartBeatInfoBean> heartBeatList) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.heartBeatList = heartBeatList;
    loader = new ImageLoader(this.activity);
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.activity);
    screenWidth = this.activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getWidth();
    imageWidth = screenWidth - 20;
    imageHeight = (screenWidth * 9) / 16;
    prefs = this.activity.getSharedPreferences("embazaar", 0);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return heartBeatList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.feedslistcontents,
                null);
        holder.ll_statusLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ll_statusLayout);
        holder.rl_listWhite = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.rl_listWhite);
        holder.rl_feedLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.rl_feedLayout);
        holder.rl_feedEventLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.rl_feedEventLayout);
        holder.rl_statusVideoLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.rl_statusVideoLayout);
        holder.rl_itemVideoLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.rl_itemVideoLayout);
        holder.rl_itemOverlayLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.rl_itemOverlayLayout);
        holder.topBar = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.topbar);
        holder.iv_userPicStatus = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_userPicStatus);
        holder.iv_userPicItem = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_userPicItem);
        holder.iv_itemPic = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_itemPic);
        holder.iv_like = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_like);
        holder.iv_comment = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_comment);
        holder.iv_share = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_share);
        holder.iv_dislike = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_dislike);
        holder.iv_statusImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_statusImage);
        holder.iv_eventImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_eventImage);
        holder.iv_statusVideoPlay = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_statusVideoplay);
        holder.iv_itemVideoPlay = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_itemVideoPlay);
        holder.iv_contact = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_contact);
        holder.tv_status = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
        holder.tv_usernameStatus = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_usernameStatus);
        holder.tv_statusLikes = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_statusLikes);
        holder.tv_statusComments = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_statusComments);
        holder.tv_statusPostedTime = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_statusPostedTime);
        holder.tv_usernameItem = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_usernameItem);
        holder.tv_itemName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_itemName);
        holder.tv_likeCommentItem = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_likeCommentItem);
        holder.tv_itemPostedTime = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_itemPostedTime);
        holder.tv_itemPrice = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_itemPrice);
        holder.tv_itemRentTime = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_itemRentTime);
        holder.tv_itemTradeFor = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_itemTradeFor);
        holder.tv_cat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cat);
        holder.tv_eventDate = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_eventdate);
        holder.tv_eventDesc = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_eventdesc);
        holder.tv_eventMonth = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_eventmonth);
        holder.tv_eventTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_eventtitle);
        holder.tv_usernameEvent = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_usernameevent);
        holder.tv_eventLikeComment = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_eventLikeComment);
        holder.vv_statusVideo = (VideoView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.vv_statusVideo);
        holder.vv_itemVideo = (VideoView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.vv_itemVideo);

        holder.iv_statusImage.getLayoutParams().width = imageWidth;
        holder.iv_statusImage.getLayoutParams().height = imageHeight;

        holder.rl_statusVideoLayout.getLayoutParams().width = imageWidth;
        holder.rl_statusVideoLayout.getLayoutParams().height = imageHeight;
        holder.rl_itemVideoLayout.getLayoutParams().width = imageWidth;
        holder.rl_itemVideoLayout.getLayoutParams().height = imageHeight;

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    if (heartBeatList.get(arg0).getLiked().equals("1")) {
        holder.iv_like.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_like_pressed);
        holder.iv_dislike.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_dislike_normal);
        holder.iv_like.setEnabled(false);
        holder.iv_dislike.setEnabled(true);
    } else if (heartBeatList.get(arg0).equals("-1")) {
        holder.iv_dislike.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_dislike_pressed);
        holder.iv_like.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_like_normal);
        holder.iv_like.setEnabled(true);
        holder.iv_dislike.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        holder.iv_like.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_like_normal);
        holder.iv_dislike.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_dislike_normal);
        holder.iv_like.setEnabled(true);
        holder.iv_dislike.setEnabled(true);
    }

    if (heartBeatList.get(arg0).getType().equals("1")) {
        holder.ll_statusLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.rl_feedLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.rl_feedEventLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        setStatus(heartBeatList.get(arg0), holder);
    } else if (heartBeatList.get(arg0).getType().equals("2")) {
        holder.ll_statusLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.rl_feedEventLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.rl_feedLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setBazaarItem(heartBeatList.get(arg0), holder);
    } else {
        holder.ll_statusLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.rl_feedLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.rl_feedEventLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setEventItem(heartBeatList.get(arg0), holder);
    }

    setClickListeners(heartBeatList.get(arg0), holder);

    return convertView;
}

private void setClickListeners(final HeartBeatInfoBean infobean,
        final ViewHolder holder) {

    holder.iv_statusVideoPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // isVideoPlaying = true;
            holder.iv_statusVideoPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.vv_statusVideo.start();
        }
    });

    holder.vv_statusVideo
            .setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                    // isVideoPlaying = false;
                    holder.iv_statusVideoPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
    holder.iv_itemVideoPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // isVideoPlaying = true;
            holder.iv_itemVideoPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.rl_itemOverlayLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.vv_itemVideo.start();
        }
    });

    holder.vv_itemVideo.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            // isVideoPlaying = false;
            holder.iv_itemVideoPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.rl_itemOverlayLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    holder.iv_userPicItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(activity, UserProfileActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("user_id", infobean.getUser_id());
            activity.startActivity(i);
            activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        }
    });

    holder.iv_contact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(activity, ChatActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("user_id2", infobean.getUser_id());
            i.putExtra("user2_name", infobean.getUsername());
            activity.startActivity(i);
            activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        }
    });

    holder.iv_userPicStatus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(activity, UserProfileActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("user_id", infobean.getUser_id());
            activity.startActivity(i);
            activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        }
    });

    holder.iv_like.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.iv_like.setEnabled(false);
            holder.iv_dislike.setEnabled(true);
            holder.iv_dislike
                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_dislike_normal);
            holder.iv_like.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_like_pressed);
            Hashtable<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            params.put("user_id", prefs.getString("user_id", ""));
            params.put("post_id", infobean.getId());
            params.put("post_type", infobean.getType());
            new Like().execute(params);
        }
    });

    holder.iv_dislike.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.iv_like.setEnabled(false);
            holder.iv_dislike.setEnabled(true);
            holder.iv_like.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_like_normal);
            holder.iv_dislike
                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_dislike_pressed);
            Hashtable<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            params.put("user_id", prefs.getString("user_id", ""));
            params.put("post_id", infobean.getId());
            params.put("post_type", infobean.getType());
            new Dislike().execute(params);

        }
    });

    holder.iv_share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            share();
        }
    });
}

private void setStatus(HeartBeatInfoBean heartBeatInfoBean,
        ViewHolder holder) {
    try {
        int number = 0;
        loader.DisplayImage(heartBeatInfoBean.getUimage(),
                holder.iv_userPicStatus, 1);
        holder.tv_usernameStatus.setText(heartBeatInfoBean.getUsername());
        holder.tv_statusPostedTime.setText(heartBeatInfoBean
                .getTime_since());
        holder.tv_statusLikes.setText(heartBeatInfoBean.getLike_count()
                + " Likes");
        holder.tv_statusComments.setText(heartBeatInfoBean.getComments()
                + " Comments");

        if (heartBeatInfoBean.getImagesList().size() > 0) {
            number = 1;
        } else if (!heartBeatInfoBean.getVideo().equals("")) {
            number = 2;
        } else if (!heartBeatInfoBean.getCheckin_loc_name().equals("")) {
            number = 3;
        } else {
            number = 0;
        }
        if (!heartBeatInfoBean.getTitle().equals("")) {
            if (number == 1) {
                holder.iv_statusImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.rl_statusVideoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.tv_status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.tv_status.setText(heartBeatInfoBean.getTitle());
                if (EmBazaarApplicationGlobal.isLoad()) {
                    loader.DisplayImage1(heartBeatInfoBean.getImagesList()
                            .get(0)
                            + "&w="
                            + imageWidth
                            + "&h="
                            + imageHeight + "&zc=0", holder.iv_statusImage,
                            R.drawable.img_place);
                }
            } else if (number == 2) {
                holder.iv_statusImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.rl_statusVideoLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.iv_statusVideoPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.tv_status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.tv_status.setText(heartBeatInfoBean.getTitle());
                if (EmBazaarApplicationGlobal.isLoad()) {
                    holder.vv_statusVideo.setVideoURI(Uri
                            .parse(heartBeatInfoBean.getVideo()));
                    // if (!isVideoPlaying) {
                    // isVideoPlaying = true;
                    holder.vv_statusVideo.start();
                    // }
                }
            } else if (number == 3) {
                holder.iv_statusImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.rl_statusVideoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.tv_status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                int begIndex = heartBeatInfoBean.getTitle().indexOf(
                        heartBeatInfoBean.getCheckin_loc_name());
                int endIndex = begIndex
                        + heartBeatInfoBean.getCheckin_loc_name().length();
                String firstString = heartBeatInfoBean.getTitle()
                        .substring(0, begIndex + 1);
                String secondString = heartBeatInfoBean.getTitle()
                        .substring(endIndex + 1,
                                heartBeatInfoBean.getTitle().length());
                holder.tv_status.setText(
                        Html.fromHtml(firstString + "<b color='blue'>"
                                + heartBeatInfoBean.getCheckin_loc_name()
                                + "</b>)" + secondString),
                        TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            } else {
                holder.iv_statusImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.rl_statusVideoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.tv_status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.tv_status.setText(heartBeatInfoBean.getTitle());
            }
        } else {
            switch (number) {
            case 0:
                holder.iv_statusImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.rl_statusVideoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.tv_status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.tv_status.setText(heartBeatInfoBean.getTitle());
                break;
            case 1:
                holder.iv_statusImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.rl_statusVideoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.tv_status.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (EmBazaarApplicationGlobal.isLoad()) {
                    loader.DisplayImage1(heartBeatInfoBean.getImagesList()
                            .get(0)
                            + "&w="
                            + imageWidth
                            + "&h="
                            + imageHeight + "&zc=0", holder.iv_statusImage,
                            R.drawable.img_place);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                holder.iv_statusImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.rl_statusVideoLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.tv_status.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.iv_statusVideoPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (EmBazaarApplicationGlobal.isLoad()) {
                    holder.vv_statusVideo.setVideoURI(Uri
                            .parse(heartBeatInfoBean.getVideo()));
                    // if (!isVideoPlaying) {
                    // isVideoPlaying = true;
                    holder.vv_statusVideo.start();
                    // }
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                holder.iv_statusImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.rl_statusVideoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.tv_status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                int begIndex = heartBeatInfoBean.getTitle().indexOf(
                        heartBeatInfoBean.getCheckin_loc_name());
                int endIndex = begIndex
                        + heartBeatInfoBean.getCheckin_loc_name().length();
                String firstString = heartBeatInfoBean.getTitle()
                        .substring(0, begIndex + 1);
                String secondString = heartBeatInfoBean.getTitle()
                        .substring(endIndex + 1,
                                heartBeatInfoBean.getTitle().length());
                holder.tv_status.setText(
                        Html.fromHtml(firstString + "<b color='blue'>"
                                + heartBeatInfoBean.getCheckin_loc_name()
                                + "</b>)" + secondString),
                        TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setBazaarItem(HeartBeatInfoBean heartBeatInfoBean,
        ViewHolder holder) {
    try {
        GradientDrawable topBg = (GradientDrawable) holder.topBar
                .getBackground();
        loader.DisplayImage(heartBeatInfoBean.getUimage(),
                holder.iv_userPicItem, 1);
        holder.tv_usernameItem.setText("by "
                + heartBeatInfoBean.getUsername());
        holder.tv_itemPostedTime.setText(heartBeatInfoBean.getTime_since());
        holder.tv_itemName.setText(heartBeatInfoBean.getTitle());
        holder.tv_likeCommentItem.setText(heartBeatInfoBean.getLike_count()
                + " likes   " + heartBeatInfoBean.getComments()
                + " comments");
        if (heartBeatInfoBean.getUser_id().equals(
                prefs.getString("user_id", ""))) {
            holder.iv_contact.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.iv_contact.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (!heartBeatInfoBean.getVideo().equals("")) {
            holder.vv_itemVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.iv_itemPic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.rl_itemOverlayLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.iv_itemVideoPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (EmBazaarApplicationGlobal.isLoad()) {
                holder.vv_itemVideo.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(heartBeatInfoBean
                        .getVideo()));
                // if (!isVideoPlaying) {
                // isVideoPlaying = true;
                holder.vv_itemVideo.start();
                // }
            }
        } else {
            holder.vv_itemVideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.iv_itemPic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.rl_itemOverlayLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (EmBazaarApplicationGlobal.isLoad()) {
                loader.DisplayImage1(
                        heartBeatInfoBean.getImagesList().get(0) + "&w="
                                + imageWidth + "&h=" + imageHeight
                                + "&zc=0", holder.iv_itemPic,
                        R.drawable.img_place);
            }
        }
        if (heartBeatInfoBean.getSub_type().equals("1")) {
            topBg.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));
            topBg.setStroke(1, Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));
            holder.tv_cat.setText("FOR SALE");
            holder.tv_itemRentTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tv_itemTradeFor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tv_itemPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tv_itemPrice.setText("$" + heartBeatInfoBean.getPrice());
        } else if (heartBeatInfoBean.getSub_type().equals("2")) {
            topBg.setColor(Color.parseColor("#66c823"));
            topBg.setStroke(1, Color.parseColor("#66c823"));
            holder.tv_cat.setText("FOR RENT");
            holder.tv_itemRentTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tv_itemRentTime
                    .setText(heartBeatInfoBean.getRent_type());
            holder.tv_itemTradeFor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tv_itemPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tv_itemPrice.setText("$" + heartBeatInfoBean.getPrice());
        } else if (heartBeatInfoBean.getSub_type().equals("3")) {
            topBg.setColor(Color.parseColor("#e0056d"));
            topBg.setStroke(1, Color.parseColor("#e0056d"));
            holder.tv_cat.setText("FOR TRADE");
            holder.tv_itemRentTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tv_itemTradeFor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tv_itemPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tv_itemTradeFor.setText("Trade For "
                    + heartBeatInfoBean.getTrade_for());
        } else {
            topBg.setColor(Color.parseColor("#701a7d"));
            topBg.setStroke(1, Color.parseColor("#701a7d"));
            holder.tv_cat.setText("FOR FREE");
            holder.tv_itemRentTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tv_itemTradeFor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tv_itemPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setEventItem(HeartBeatInfoBean heartBeatInfoBean,
        ViewHolder holder) {
    GradientDrawable listWhite = (GradientDrawable) holder.rl_listWhite
            .getBackground();
    listWhite.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    listWhite.setStroke(1, Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    holder.tv_eventDate.setText(getDate(heartBeatInfoBean.getEvent_date()));
    holder.tv_eventMonth
            .setText(getMonth(heartBeatInfoBean.getEvent_date()));
    holder.tv_eventDesc.setText(heartBeatInfoBean.getDescription());
    holder.tv_usernameEvent
            .setText("by " + heartBeatInfoBean.getUsername());
    holder.tv_eventTitle.setText(heartBeatInfoBean.getTitle());
    holder.tv_eventLikeComment.setText(heartBeatInfoBean.getLike_count()
            + " Likes  " + heartBeatInfoBean.getComments() + " Comments");

    if (EmBazaarApplicationGlobal.isLoad()) {
        loader.DisplayImage1(heartBeatInfoBean.getImagesList().get(0)
                + "&w=" + imageWidth + "&h=" + imageHeight + "&zc=0",
                holder.iv_eventImage, R.drawable.img_place);
    }

}

static class ViewHolder {

    ImageView iv_userPicStatus, iv_userPicItem, iv_like, iv_comment,
            iv_share, iv_dislike, iv_statusImage, iv_eventImage,
            iv_itemPic, iv_statusVideoPlay, iv_itemVideoPlay, iv_contact;
    VideoView vv_statusVideo, vv_itemVideo;
    TextView tv_status, tv_usernameStatus, tv_statusLikes,
            tv_statusComments, tv_statusPostedTime, tv_cat,
            tv_usernameItem, tv_itemName, tv_likeCommentItem,
            tv_itemPostedTime, tv_itemPrice, tv_itemRentTime,
            tv_itemTradeFor, tv_eventDate, tv_eventMonth, tv_eventTitle,
            tv_usernameEvent, tv_eventDesc, tv_eventLikeComment;
    LinearLayout ll_statusLayout;
    RelativeLayout rl_feedLayout, topBar, rl_feedEventLayout, rl_listWhite,
            rl_statusVideoLayout, rl_itemVideoLayout, rl_itemOverlayLayout;
}

public class Like extends
        AsyncTask<Hashtable<String, String>, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Hashtable<String, String>... params) {
        String jsonString = "";
        try {
            jsonString = Connection.sendPostData(
                    EmBazaarConstants.ACTION_LIKE, params[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    if (jObject.getString("success").equals("1")) {

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public class Dislike extends
        AsyncTask<Hashtable<String, String>, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Hashtable<String, String>... params) {
        String jsonString = "";
        try {
            jsonString = Connection.sendPostData(
                    EmBazaarConstants.ACTION_DISLIKE, params[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    if (jObject.getString("success").equals("1")) {

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@SuppressLint({ "SimpleDateFormat", "DefaultLocale" })
private String getMonth(String event_date) {
    String month = "";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date1 = format.parse(event_date);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        month = sdf.format(date1);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return month.toUpperCase();
}

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private String getDate(String event_date) {
    String date = "";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date1 = format.parse(event_date);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
        date = sdf.format(date1);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}

protected void share() {
    String shareBody = "Check out EmBazaar... http://www.code-brew.com/";
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share To:"));
}

}
```

**feedlistcontents.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/ll_statusLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/feedstatus_layout"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/rl_feedLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/feeditem_layout"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/rl_feedEventLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/feed_event_layout"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/ll_like"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/like_layout" />

</LinearLayout>
```

like_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_border_grey_bottom"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="4" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_like"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_like_normal" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_comment"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_message_tab_normal" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_share"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_share_normal" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_dislike"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_dislike_normal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The only difference I can see is that there is no reference to `ll_like` in your holder. For the other views which work, there `<include>`ed layout is referenced but not the `ll_like`. Have you tried to add that layout to your holder to see if it becomes visible in a `findViewById`?

Comment: @CodeMonkey I don't think that referencing ll_like will do the trick because we can still access the views inside <include> ed without referencing <include> ed layout.Also I am using references for other <include> ed layout because I have to toggle their visibilities depending upon the content but the ll_like layout remains the same for each row.

Comment: Sorry @Mukesh, I missed where you said `findViewById` was working.

Comment: it's Okay @CodeMonkey